# XDVI and composition managers

Tags: tools, linux

I am trying to use XDVI (as shipped by TeXLive 2010) in a Linux X11 desktop which is using the Compiz compositing manager. Now, when the DVI file being displayed changes, I have to click on the window to have it update: simply giving focus to the window does not cause XDVI to reload the file because (I guess) Compiz makes it believe that it is always being mapped onscreen.

Is there a way to have XDVI behave more reasonably in my situation?

Comment: I generally use evince which updates whenever the file has changed (also I generally compile directly to pdf). Maybe it is possible to configure xdvi so that it watches for file changes?

Comment: Yes. Just run it with the `-watchfile <n>` flag, where `<n>` is the number of seconds to wait between checking for file changes. See `man xdvi` for more details.

Comment: @Willie: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `xdvi` with the `-watchfile <n>` flag, where `<n>` is the number of seconds to wait between checking for file changes. See `man xdvi` for more details and more options.

To make it permanent, you can also set the appropriate option in `~/.xdvirc` on your linux box. See the manpage again for the correct syntax.

---

Of course, this only works if the problem was on the `xdvi` side, and not on the Compiz side; if Compiz does not redraw the window in the situation, whatever you do to `xdvi` won't help.